# Implementing GGX VNDF importance sampling with DXR

Tags: raytracing, rendering, shader, brdf, hlsl

I am currently implementing the GGX specular BRDF in a DXR raytracer using the importance sampling method describe by [Heitz](http://jcgt.org/published/0007/04/01/paper.pdf)

I am sampling the VNDF with:

```
//https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01509746/document
inline float3 VNDF_GGX(in float3 wo, float roughness2, float rand1, float rand2)
{
    //Strecht view vector
    float3 view = normalize(float3(wo.x * roughness2, wo.y, wo.z * roughness2));

    //Orthonormal basis
    float3 lensq = pow(view.x, 2) + pow(view.z, 2);
    float3 t1 = (lensq > 0.0f) ? normalize(cross(view, float3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f))) : float3(1, 0, 0);
    float3 t2 = cross(view, t1);

    //project
    float r = sqrt(rand1);
    float phi = 2.0f * pi * rand2;
    float p1 = r * cos(phi);
    float p2 = r * sin(phi);

    float s = 0.5f * (1.0f + view.y);
    p2 = (1.0f - s) * sqrt(1.0f - pow(p1, 2.0f)) + s * p2;

    float3 n = p1 * t1 + p2 * t2 + sqrt(max(0.0f, 1.0f - pow(p1, 2.0f) - pow(p2, 2.0f))) * view;

    //unstrech normal and renormalize
    float3 n_out = normalize(float3(roughness2 * n.x, max(0.0f, n.y), roughness2 * n.z));

    return n_out;
}
```

where wo is the view direction in tangent space, roughness2 is the material roughness [0;1] squared and rand1/rand2 are uniform random numbers [0;1] sampled from a texture. I am using the exact algorithm described by Heitz except using y-up instead of z-up.

Using the microfacet normal  ***m*** calculated like this I then acquire the sample direction ***wi*** by reflecting the world ray direction ***-wo*** in tangent space about the microfacet normal ***m***.

```
void ImportanceSampleGGXVNDF(float3 wo, Material material, inout float3 wi, inout float reflectance, float2 randSeed, bool isInVec, inout float fschlick)
{
    float roughness2 = pow(material.roughness, 2.0f);
    float3 m = VNDF_GGX(wo, roughness2, randSeed.x, randSeed.y);

    wi = normalize(reflect(-wo, m));

    float3 normalTangentSpace = float3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    fschlick = FresnelSchlick(m, wi, isInVec ? material.ior1 : 1.0f, isInVec ? 1.0f : material.ior1);
    float G1 = SmithMaskingGGX(wi, wo, normalTangentSpace, pow(roughness2, 2));
    float G2 = SmithShdowingGGX(wo, wi, normalTangentSpace, pow(roughness2, 2));

    reflectance = fschlick *(G2 / G1);
}
```

Where wo is the view direction, wi is the sample direction in tangent space, reflectance equaling the BRDF term (everything else cancels out according to Heitz! See [here](https://schuttejoe.github.io/post/ggximportancesamplingpart2/) details of the derivation)

This however seems to be producing invalid sampling Directions for ray directions with negative values in y or z component resulting in invalid light probes.

[image: invalid samples for negative z direction]

Comparing with similar implementations (including: [here](https://gist.github.com/mebiusbox/32995b0d133a82a05b4023e512addb77) implementing the exact same method, [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/Q2RTX/issues/40) also implementing the same method and [here](https://github.com/TheRealMJP/DXRPathTracer/blob/master/SampleFramework12/v1.02/Shaders/Sampling.hlsl) using an algorithm described in an older paper also published by [Heitz](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01509746/document)) sadly yielded no solution.

The final output color is computed via

````
    ImportanceSampleGGXVNDF(tangentSpaceDir, halfVec, l_materialCB[0], rayDir, reflectance, rand, isInVec, fschlick);

    newRayDir = tangentToWorldSpace(rayDir, tangent, bitangent, triangleNormal);

    ray.Direction = newRayDir;
    ray.TMin = 0.0001f;
    ray.TMax = 10000.0; //Maximum travel distance of ray
    reflected = TraceReflectiveRay(ray, currNumRecursions);

    reflected *= reflectance;
```
````